# Difference between BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE and BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I am writing an application where I need to fetch Device Battery status.

Here I found following these two property :

```
 1. BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE and
 2. BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL
```

What is difference between both. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you know google? -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_LEVEL

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo thanks for ur kindness.. Helton make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EXTRA_LEVEL - integer field containing the current battery level, from 0 to EXTRA_SCALE.
EXTRA_SCALE - Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer containing the maximum battery level.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html